# What happens if a person without Upanayana gets married?

Tags: brahman, marriage, life, upanayanam, bramhacharya

In Brahmins community, it is said one have to attain Bramhachari by having Upanayana and later get into married life. Suppose what if the person never got Upanayana but married? Like run away from home and got love marriage even from the same community or different?

Is he considered to be out of Brahmins community? Can Upanayana be considered even after marriage?

Also how is this applicable with Vishwakarmas and other communities who follow similar Upanayana concept?

Answer (score 5):

A twice-born person, without having the Upanayana within the prescribed time, is called a Vratya in the scriptures. He is treated like an uninitiated person (a Shudra) although he might be a Brahmin by birth.

There are some remedies available for him (like the Vratyastoma Yajna) performing which he can regain his status of a twice-born.

> 71 For a Brahmin the time for initiation does not lapse until the
> sixteenth year, 72 for a Ksatriya until the twenty-second year, 73 and
> for a Vais´ya until the twenty-fourth year. **74 After that time they
> become excluded from the Sa¯vitrı¯;**
>
> **75 and no one should initiate them, teach them, officiate at their
> sacrifices, or enter into marriage alliances with them.**
>
> 76 A man who is excluded from the Sa¯vitrı¯ should perform the
> Uddalaka penance: 77 for two months he should live on barley gruel,
> for one month on milk, for a fortnight on curd, for eight days on
> ghee, for six days on food received unasked, and for three days on
> water; and he should fast for a day and night.
>
> 78 Alternatively, he may participate in the ritual bath that concludes
> a horse sacrifice; 79 or he may perform the Vratyastoma sacrifice.
>
> **Dharmasutras of Vashishta 11.71-79**

**What happens if they marry?**

Nothing will happen. They can marry but then the sons fathered by them will also be Vratyas who are not qualified for initiation (Upanayana).

> **16 Sons fathered by an uninitiated man are Vratyas, excluded from initiation**––so state the wise with equal reference to the three
> classes.
>
> **Dharmasutras of Baudhayana 1.16.16**

I am not sure though if the remedies mentioned in the first quote can be performed after marriage or not possibly not.